# Create new dataframe columns from old dataframe rows using for loop --> N/A values

Tags: pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I created a dataframe df1:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('FBK_var_conc_1.csv', names = ['Cycle', 'SQ'])  
df1 = df1['SQ'].copy()                            
df1 = df1.to_frame()                               
df1.head(n=10)


    SQ
0   2430.0
1   2870.0
2   2890.0
3   3270.0
4   3350.0
5   3520.0
6   26900.0
7   26300.0
8   28400.0
9   3230.0
```

And then created a second dataframe df2, that I want to fill with the row values of df 1:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
for x in range(12):
    y='Experiment %d' % (x+1)
    df2[y]= df1.iloc[3*x:3*x+3]
df2
```

I get the column names from Experiment 1 - Experiment 12 in df2 and the first column i filled with the right values, but all following columns are filled with N/A.

```
>       Experiment 1    Experiment 2    Experiment 3    Experiment 4    Experiment 5    Experiment 6    Experiment 7    Experiment 8    Experiment 9    Experiment
> 10    Experiment 11   Experiment 12
>     0 2430.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>     1 2870.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
>     2 2890.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I've been looking at this for the last 2 hours but can't figure out why the columns after column 1 aren't filled with values.

Desired output:

```
Experiment 1    Experiment 2    Experiment 3    Experiment 4    Experiment 5    Experiment 6    Experiment 7    Experiment 8    Experiment 9    Experiment 10   Experiment 11   Experiment 12
2430    3270    26900   3230    2940    243000  256000  249000  2880    26100   3890    33400
2870    3350    26300   3290    3180    242000  254000  250000  3390    27900   3730    30700
2890    3520    28400   3090    3140    253000  260000  237000  3510    27400   3760    29600
```

Comment: Can you add `df1.head(n=5)`

Comment: Yes, I added it

Comment: Can you add to your question which would be your desired output for the first 5 rows?

Comment: Yes, I edited it into my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.

I had to use `.values`

So the final line of the loop has to be:

```
df2[y] = df1.iloc[3*x:3*x+3].values
```

and I get the right output